# SLURM with "partial" head node

Tags: hpc, slurm

I am trying to install SLURM with NFS on a small ubuntu 18.04 HPC cluster, in a typical fashion, e.g. configure controller (slurmctld) and clients (slurmd) and shared directory, etc. What I am curious about is, is there a way to set it up such that there is a controller on a portion of the head node, and other drives in the head node are used by the resource partitioning routine, like the other nodes? Is there a way to accomplish this using the SLURM configuration file?

I am essentially asking how to maximise the resources if the controller will only be doing light work.

Thank you, cheers!

Comment: I can't fully understand your question. NFS has nothing to do with SLURM. What you're trying to achieve? Do you want to use your headnode (where you run slurmctld) as a computing node so you can run both slurmctld and slurmd?

Comment: The NFS was a possibly irrelevant detail, except for maybe if the shared home drive was impacted by the set up. Yes, this is what I wanted to do, computations on head node instead of wasting its resources, since it is a small cluster and I want to maximize everything. In any case, this is no longer my project, so I have no interest in it anymore. But, if you have tips for the future I would gladly hear them

Comment: I will write an answer, but yes you can run slurmd on the headnode, we usually do this on small machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to consume the headnode as a compute node. This is perfectly normal on small clusters and even on workstations that have SLURM as a queue system to consume it as an easier way to enqueue jobs or to share the compute power among a group of users that have access to this workstation.

To do this just enable `slurmd` on the same machine that runs `slurmctld`. Remember to add the respective node and partition entry on `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` with the compute specifications. As example, you should have something like this:

```
ClusterName=Cloyster
ControlMachine=charizard.cluster.example.com
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/ctld
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurm/d
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=MEMLOCK
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
Epilog=/etc/slurm/slurm.epilog.clean
SlurmctldParameters=enable_configless

ReturnToService=2
NodeName=charizard Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=64 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=execution Nodes=charizard Default=YES MaxTime=720:00:00 State=UP Oversubscribe=EXCLUSIVE
```

Observe that NodeName have the hostname of the control machine.

Comment: Assigning a slurmctld management daemon to the head looks like exactly what would be needed. Thanks!